# Deleting extra bytes from decrypted file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

I am using Blowfish java encryption without padding to encrypt file in sequence:

- generate session key
- prepare file header (algorithms, key length, mode, encrypted session key with rsa public key)
- encrypt file with session key

inverse for decryption.

I end with decrypted file that has size = original file size + some extra bytes (amount depens on original file size, block size etc.).
How can i make that decrypted file size = original. Obviously i have to cut extra bytes, but how can I recognize how many of them without knowledge about original file size.

Edit. I am using stream cipher. No Padding and Blowfish is must be, because it is a school project.

Comment: use padding? put the size in the header?

Comment: I want to produce worng decrypted file when someone insert wrong password, so I can't use padding. Also  inlucuding file size is prohibitet on my project

Comment: If you want to detect an incorrect decryption key you need to add authentication to the encrypted data, usually with a MAC prepended to the encrypted data. Decryption by itself can not determine incorrect decryption.

Comment: If you are looking for current best practice security use AES, not Blowfish. Use PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, CBC mode, a random IV and encryption authentication with a constant time error detection. Or, just use HTTPS, it encrypts all data in transit.

Comment: Update in edited post

Comment: Get a better school, school should prepare you for the real world where Blowfish should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Blowfish is block cipher, so it compresses blocks. Its block size is 64 bits. If you try to encrypt 65 bits (no matter you have explicitly selected padding of not), the encrypted size will be 128 bits.

If you want the encrypted text to be 65 bits, you have to use stream cipher.

Comment: Stream ciphers are difficult to get correct, padding is the usual solution.

Comment: if you skip manually set padding, zero padding is automatically applied

Comment: Java crypto never does zero padding by default, at least unless you use a nonstandard custom provider which the OP would *probably* have mentioned. But something in the app easily can in a way that isn't very obvious, like `Arrays.copyOf (a, size_rounded_up)`. JCA also can't do non-integral bytes like 65 bits, but does have the same issue for 9 bytes versus 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid padding with a block cypher like Blowfish, use Counter Mode (CTR).  This effectively turns a block cypher into a stream cypher.  Rather than padding, you just throw away the last part of the generated bytestream so your cyphertext is the same length as the original plaintext.

You might also check that your cyphertext doesn't have things added at the front, like the Nonce.  That would have the same effect of lengthening the cyphertext.

As has been pointed out, Blowfish is not a good choice.  Use AES instead, or one of the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) cyphers is you want an actual stream cypher.